# What is this equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, notation

A while ago I came across this funny little bit of graffiti:

[image]

What is this equation? What does it mean? What are the symbols?

The notation reminds me of quantum mechanics, so I am tagging accordingly.

Comment: I suppose you've never heard of [Dirac's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) then?

Comment: @KyleKanos Heard of it, but don't know it :)

Comment: Every introductory QM textbook I've seen introduces the very equation you wrote at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's the time independent Schrödinger equation written using Dirac notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-independent_equation).